# How to Change view(XIB) after imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am new on iphone and objective-c development.

I want to know how i can change the view (XIB File) after the camera takes a picture.

Can anyone help me or share some code? I am searching for this since a week :(
After finishing the app, i am ready to share my project and/or make a tutorial.

Infos about my App: i want to scan barcodes and save the barcodes in my app.
For scanning barcodes iam using the ZBarSDK.
I hava a TabBarController, on the first Tab, i can open the camera. 
After the scan process i want to jump to the second tab (another XIB File) and show the results.

Thanks for any help.

Here my code of the first tab (ScanCodeViewController):

.h

```
#import < UIKit/UIKit.h >

@class OutPutCodeViewController;

@interface ScanCodeViewController : UIViewController <ZBarReaderDelegate> {
 IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
 OutPutCodeViewController *output;         
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
@property (nonatomic, retain) OutPutCodeViewController *output;

- (IBAction) scanButton;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ScanCodeViewController.h"


@implementation ScanCodeViewController

@synthesize img;
@synthesize output;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[img release];
[super dealloc];
}


- (IBAction) scanButton {
 NSLog(@"Scanbutton wurde geklickt!");

 ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
 reader.readerDelegate = self;

 ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

 [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];

 [self presentModalViewController:reader animated: YES];
 [reader release];
 }


- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
 NSLog(@"Entered imagePickerController");


 // ADD: get the decode results
 id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
 ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
 for(symbol in results) {
 break;
 }

 img.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
 [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];


 //[self presentModalViewController:output animated:YES]; //by using this, app chrashes 

}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
 [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

}


@end
```

And here the Secong Tab (OutPutCodeViewController)

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface OutPutCodeViewController : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UIImageView *resultImage;
 IBOutlet UITextField *resultText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *resultText;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "OutPutCodeViewController.h"


@implementation OutPutCodeViewController

@synthesize resultImage;
@synthesize resultText;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [resultImage release];
 [resultText release];

[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

It is not possible to set more animate:YES.
Here is the sample and right code.

I hope it helps others.

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{

    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        break;

[reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];

    TableDetailViewController *tc = [[TableDetailViewController alloc]         initWithNibName:@"TableDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    tc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:tc animated:YES];
    [tc release];   

}
```

brush51

Answer (score 0):

In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` you should call `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]` to switch to the second tab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Can you tell me how i can show a XIB-File after the imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: ?  My aim is to load another XIB File and show in this loaded XIB-File the captured Picture and encoded Code